# How computers convert decimal to binary integers

Tags: binary, decimal

This is surely a duplicate, but I was not able to find an answer to the following question.

Let's consider the decimal integer `14`. We can obtain its binary representation, `1110`, using e.g. the *divide-by-2* method (`%` represents the modulus operand):

```
14 % 2 = 0
 7 % 2 = 1
 3 % 2 = 1
 1 % 2 = 1
```

but how computers convert decimal to binary integers?

The above method would require the computer to perform arithmetic and, as far as I understand, because arithmetic is performed on binary numbers, it seems we would be back dealing with the same issue.

I suppose that any other algorithmic method would suffer the same problem. How do computers convert decimal to binary integers?

**Update**: Following a discussion with [Code-Apprentice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1440565/code-apprentice) (see comments under his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49034693/8970640)), here is a reformulation of the question in two cases of interest:

*a)* How the conversion to binary is performed when the user types integers on a keyboard?

*b)* Given a mathematical operation in a programming language, say `12 / 3`, how does the conversion from decimal to binary is done when running the program, so that the computer can do the arithmetic?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, like you mention in one of you comments, if compiler has a small look-up table to associate decimal integers to binary integers then it can be done with simple binary multiplications and additions.
Look-up table has to contain binary associations for single decimal digits and decimal ten, hundred, thousand, etc.
Decimal 14 can be transformed to binary by multipltying binary 1 by binary 10 and added binary 4.
Decimal 149 would be binary 1 multiplied by binary 100, added to binary 4 multiplied by binary 10 and added binary 9 at the end.

Answer (score 0):

### Decimal are misunderstood in a program

let's take an example from c language

```c
int x = 14;
```

here 14 is not decimal its two characters 1 and 4 which are written together to be 14

we know that characters are just representation for some binary value
1 for 00110001
4 for 00110100

[full ascii table for characters can be seen here](https://www.asciitable.com/)

so 14 in charcter form actually written as binary 00110001 00110100
00110001 00110100 => this binary is made to look as 14 on computer screen (so we think it as decimal)

we know number 14 evntually should become 14 = 1110
or we can pad it with zero to be
14 = 00001110

for this to happen computer/processor only need to do binary to binary conversion i.e.
00110001 00110100  to 00001110
and we are all set

Answer (score -1):

## There is only binary

The computer stores all data as binary. It does not convert from decimal to binary since binary is its native language. When the computer displays a number it will convert from the binary representation to any base, which by default is decimal.

A key concept to understand here is the difference between the computers internal storage and the representation as characters on your monitor. If you want to display a number as binary, you can write an algorithm in code to do the exact steps that you performed by hand. You then print out the characters `1` and `0` as calculated by the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks @Code-Apprentice. But how the computer converts a decimal integer, that is input by the user, to a binary form (say, e.g., for storing it)?

Comment: @unfolx The computer cannot do this automatically. You have to write a program that does it. (Note that there are functions in most popular languages that can do this.) The program relies on how we represent numbers in base 10.

Comment: I feel that the 'problem' of conversion still remain. Given that the program will be run by the computer, any method to get the binary representation from this program would require the computer to know how to convert a decimal integer in order to perform the arithmetic that would yield the result of the conversion. This is the snake biting its own tail, so obviously there is something incorrect with this rationale.

Comment: @unfolx The computer performs arithmetic directly with the data stored in memory. It does not convert numbers to decimal form before adding them, for example. The numbers are only converted to decimal when the computer displays them for humans to read.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your last comment. Note that I was not concerned with conversion from binary to decimal, but only the reverse one. My previous comment may be was not clear. At any rate, having searched further on the web, it seems the point I was missing was the following: the computer knows how to convert decimal integers to binary integers by using a look-up table to associate each of the digits to their respective binary representations (so it knows that, e.g., `1` is `0001`), and then by doing arithmetic on these representations to get the binary representation of the whole number.

Comment: @unfolx That does not sound correct to me. Internally, the computer stores numbers in binary and does arithmetic directly without any conversion. As I have stated several times, conversion only happens when a user types a number or the computer prints a number to a monitor.

Comment: Let me rephrase my original question following your comments. How does a program convert decimal to binary? The program cannot use arithmetic directly on the decimal integer to perform this conversion, since the arithmetic would be performed by the computer and the computer does arithmetic on binary representations.

Comment: (For the sources about the lookup table I mentioned: this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/6taf9a/eli5_how_does_a_computer_convert_decimal_to/) and this [Physics Forum post](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-computer-converts-decimal-to-binary-to-decimal.632736/). One can scroll down directly to the answer of Schnutzel and DrGreg, respectively.)

Comment: @unfolx I do not see any lookup tables in either of those threads.

Comment: @unfolx I guess I don't understand what you are asking. Since a computer stores numbers in binary, there is no need to convert from decimal to binary. The numbers are **already in binary**. Are you referring to what happens when the user types numbers on a keyboard and how those are converted to a numerical value?

Comment: *Re lookup table.* In the Reddit post, Schnutzel speaks about a conversion table; further down mmmmmmBacon12345 mentioned a lookup table. In the PhysicsForum post, there is no mention, DrGreg only indicates that the conversion on each digit is known (I assumed this was known through a conversion table, mentioned in the former post). *Re your question.* Yes, this is it. I would have two questions, maybe equivalent...

Comment: ... *a)* How the conversion to binary is performed when the user types numbers on a keyboard? *b)* Given a mathematical operation in a programming language, say `12 / 3`, how does the conversion from decimal to binary is done when running the program, so that the computer can do the arithmetic?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The questioned conversion from decimal to binaries has to happen: You create code in e.g. C++. This code contains a number. That number has to be transformed to binary, either the compiler does it, or the underlying layer...

Comment: @goulashsoup Yes, when you write a int literal in your code, the compiler will convert the characters into a numerical value in the compiled code. When the compiled binary runs, then the numerical value is loaded into a register or into memory as a binary value.